# Fetch posts from Facebook page using FB API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

Up until this summer, I had a website (not my website) which was fetching it's responding fb page posts and was displaying it on a page.

I was doing it using the app-token, which now doesn't work since it now requires `Page Public Content Access` to get those data, which in turn requires it to be registered as an app, which is beyond the scope of this.

I tried creating a non-expiring user-access token, but they seem to expire after 3 months, no matter the "trick" I tried using.

Is there any suggestion of how I can get over it?

Maybe an automated api call that would refresh the token with no user interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did it!

Now the how: I did it with the `manage_pages` access, not with `Page Public Content`.
I went back and forth a total of 5 times to get this to pass and a bit over a week.

First of all `Page Public Content` is only allowed by Facebook when you want to analyze data from other pages as well, so you better not mess with it.

What I had to do to get the request approved is specify on your application for requesting the access that there is no login, provide a copy of your code on the description and I also included a url where it was working with a user generated token through javascript, so they could review the code through a web debugger.

After that you get a manage_pages token which you can use to fetch your pages posts

I really hope some of those things were an overkill, but, like I said, I had to submit a review a total of 5 times, so on the last try I went all in...

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a Page Token (NOT a User Token) for the Page if you manage it - but it will expire. There is no way around that. OR you apply for Page Public Content Access so you can use an App Token.

Auto-refreshing would make the whole point of expiring Tokens pointless, you need user interaction for that.

Comment: I cannot apply for Public Content Access, since it requires a full business registration on facebook's part. Is there an API call perhaps to generate tokens?

Comment: no, there is no other way. if you could just generate tokens without user interaction...well, that would make the whole point of tokens void.

Comment: I don't get why a page would require a user access token or special privileges to access it's own content in the first place. There should be a different way, no?

Comment: the page does not require that, you require specific permission to access data of the page. it is very simple, you either own the page and you can use a page token of that page, or you do not own it and you need to apply for PPCA - because you should not just grab stuff of pages you do not own if not for a good reason. there is no different way.

Comment: But I want to take data from my page (a page I have admin rights), but the page access token requires special permissions

Comment: there are no special permissions, just manage_pages - and if it is your own page, you do not need to get anything approved by facebook.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? What is the endpoint i should request, because `/{page-id}/posts` asks for more permissions

Comment: just authorize with the manage_pages permission and create a page token with /me/accounts?fields=id,access_token

Comment: But, this creates an expirable user token

Comment: no, it creates a page token that will expire after a few months, if you create it with an extended user token. you have to refresh it manually then: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens